# Acces to campaigns in Standard Platform User Profile

Tags: permissions, profile, standard-objects, campaign

We have a user with "Salesforce Platform" license. How can we give campaigns access to "Standard Platform User" Profile user.

Answer (score 5):

Salesforce platform license does not allow to have access of Campaign object.

> Designed for users who need access to custom apps but not to standard
>   CRM functionality. Users with this user license are entitled to use
>   custom apps developed in your organization or installed from
>   Salesforce AppExchange. In addition, they are entitled to use core
>   platform functionality such as accounts, contacts, reports,
>   dashboards, documents, and custom tabs. **These users are not entitled
>   to some user permissions and standard apps, including report
>   subscriptions and standard tabs and objects such as forecasts, leads,
>   campaigns, and opportunities.**

[Resource](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=users_license_types_available.htm&type=5)

Answer (score 2):

Access to Campaigns is granted per user, not by profiles, via the Marketing User licence. This license is a kind of Feature Licenses which you can see in the Company Information section for your org. To add a user to this licenese in Salesforce (Classic) go to Setup > Manage Users > Users, then click on the user you want to grant a Marketing User license to.

**Unfortunately, Salesforce does not provide access to Marketing License for users with user license "Salesforce Platform".**

[image]